# Is the derivative function of an elementary function continuous?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

It's well-known that $f'(x)$ is not necessarily continuous. Here is a classic counterexample:

$$f(x):=\begin{cases}0, &x=0, \\x^2\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right), &x\neq 0\end{cases},$$

where $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$, but $f'(x)$ is not continuous at $x=0$.

However, such kind of $f(x)$ is not so-called **[elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function)**. We wanna know that

> If $f(x)$ is an elementary function and differentiable everywhere,
> then whether $f'(x)$ is necessarily continuous or not.

Comment: What is the precise definition that you have been taught for the specification: *elementary function*?

Comment: Why do "we wanna know"? And do you know if the composition of functions with continuous derivatives also has continuous derivatives?

Comment: I believe the notion of elementary function is not defined function-wise, but rather as an element of a differential algebra.